# Using malloc for a typedef char name[300][300]? (C)

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

So I've got to do an exercise in C where I have to create an twodimensional array as a "field". We have been given the term `typedef char name[300][300]`. Now I want to use malloc on this typedef char name, but I can't figure out how (I'm a total beginner in C). I've searched all the way through the internet but couldn't find an example with a typedef char thing and I have no plan how I can do that. Do I have to create a pointer or some special magic to use malloc on this or what am I missing out?

Comment: "*all the way through the internet*" LOL

Comment: `name * pname = malloc(sizeof *pname);`

Comment: "*I've got to do an exercise in C  ... and I have no plan how I can do that.*" you missed the lessons, right? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`type *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` pretty much works generically.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char name[300][300]; //makes `name` a typedef for `char[300][300]`;
int main()
{
    name *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof *p); //verify that this is 300*300==90000 bytes large
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### How to use the `typedef char name[300][300]` Dynamic memory allocation?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef char name[300][300];

int main(){
    name *namelist= malloc(sizeof *namelist); // we are pointing to char [300][300]
    /* check the return value of malloc */
    if( namelist == NULL ){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        scanf("%299s",(*namelist)[i]); // dereferencing it to acccess the 2d array
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%s\n",(*namelist)[i]);
    free(namelist);
    return 0;
}
```

Here the use of the `typdef` is shown with a small code.

#### Explanation:

```
typedef char name[300][300]
```

We associate `name` with the type `char [300][300]`.

> Defines `name` as `300` elements array of `300` element array of type
>   `char`.

Now pointer to this is basically pointer to a 2d array  `char[300][300]` or simply `char (*)[300][300]`.

That's why we need to dereference the variable first `(*namelist)` and then we access the 2d array.

#### Extra points:

Why `sizeof *namelist = 90000 Byte`?
Because `*namelist` denote the 2d array. From standard §6.5.3.4

> When `sizeof` is applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned
>   char`, or `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is
>   `1`. **When applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array**.

So the array has `300 x 300 = 90000` char variables each of which is of 1 Byte. So `90000` byte.

*Emphasis added*

Comment: But where is the use of malloc there? It's part of our task to store this char name with malloc

Comment: @VeniiX.: You wanted to `malloc` it .I missed wait a sec.

Comment: @VeniiX, You should read a book or tutorial on C, to understand the concepts. getting ready made program helps no one.

Comment: @alk.: I guess this explains the idea. Correct me the error if any.

Comment: @VeniiX.: Hope this helps

Comment: Actually I am (again) a bit confused about `typedef`. You say "_We associate_ `name` _with the type_ `char [300][300]`" But isn;t the syntax `typedef <existing type> <new type>` so the `[300][300]` would have to be with the `char` and not `name`? (maybe I should read book...)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie.: Actually I am referring this from a book. I mean after answering I checked. `C A reference manual` - page 141 Chapter-5..You can check it once if you have the book. If I got the meaning wrong please let me know

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: C'mon, English semantics are simply different for C's! ;-) The cited sentence is pretty clear.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Easy rule to remember is, typedef is same as declaring a variable, except you just stick "typedef" in front.

Comment: @hide, thanks, that's easy to remember and makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you got to work with but you could also wrap `char name[300][300]` table in your own type:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct my_array_type { char name[300][300]; } my_array_type;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    my_array_type * my_table   =  malloc(sizeof  *my_table);  
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof *my_table);          

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the gain from wrapping the array inside a struct?

Comment: @alk  Thanks for the Q. A: You can easily change the content of the struct and extended it with new struct members without touching main.

Comment: Well, this is true, but how would this help in the context of the OP's question?

Comment: @alk The direct answer to the question has been given already by PSkocik. I just wanted to add a different perspective. Thanks!